# Converting foreach to Linq causes InvalidOperationException in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a Linq query that is connecting to a CRM 2013 Organization.svc web service.  The query is working correctly in that when I enumerate the items in the result, I get my expected values.

The problem comes in when I am trying to turn the list of items into a List of SelectListItems for my MVC 5 site.

If i have code like this:

```
List<SelectListItem> driverList = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var driver in drivers)
{
   driverList.Add(new SelectListItem() {Text = driver.account_name, Value = driver.account_id.ToString()});
}
```

I get no errors thrown.

However, if I try to convert it to a Linq statement (using Resharper) like this:

```
List<SelectListItem> driverList = drivers.Select(driver => new SelectListItem() {Text = driver.account_name, Value = driver.account_id.ToString()}).ToList();
```

I get an error back from runtime as follows: Invalid left 'String' and right 'Nullable`1' parameters

Do I just have to stick with a foreach in this case?

Comment: What is `drivers`? You don't show the definition in the code - my first guess is that it is not a `List` and if you change it to `drivers.ToList().Select` it will work.

Comment: drivers is a linq query that is executed against a OrganizationContext connected to CRM.  It's returning an anonymous object consisting of the account_name and account_id objects.  account_name is a string and account_id is a Guid.

Comment: It should work. Could you post the `driver` entity class?